# Should relations only be LAZY or EAGER in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm a little bit confused about the Hibernate `fetch` option. I'm using Spring Boot 2, Spring Data and Hibernate in my project. Let's say I have an entity `User`. Each `User` may have many `Post` and of course each `Post` may have many `Comment` entity. I designed the `SQL` database tables like the following;

```
User
id (PK)
username
password

Post
id (PK)
title
content
user_id (FK)

Comment
id (PK)
content
post_id (FK)
```

Therefore, if I need to list Posts of specific User, there is no need to fetch comments. `LAZY` fetch would be better of course. However, if I need to return specific post do display, I need to fetch both post and its comments. So, `EAGER` fetch should be used.

How should I define the fetch types on my classes? I am sure there is a design pattern for those relational databases but I couldn't figure out. All tutorials explain LAZY and EAGER fetch type, pros and cons but I didn't find how to do when I need to use both LAZY and EAGER. I tried to define fetches LAZY and use `Spring Data Repository` interface to ease db queries. For EAGER fetching, I tried to write a custom db queries. However, I couldn't manage to query nested joins (ie. querying all posts and its comments for a specific User or Users). I can query first users, then each users posts then each posts comments but as you know it is not how should it be.

What is the common pattern for these kind of relational data? H

Comment: You don't need to write queries all you have to do is specify how to fetch data using `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` for instance.

Comment: When I do that, it throws an LazyInitializationException if I try to reach post.comments

Comment: I think you have something wrong with your JPA configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@OneToMany` with `FetchType.LAZY`(no need to set that's the default)

```
public class Post {

    //other fields
    @OneToMany
    private List<Comment> comments;

    //getters and setters
    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

Also if you are trying to access the List outside of a transactional scope then you will get `LazyInitializationException` since hibernate does not issue additional query(s) to get value for `FetchType.LAZY` collections.

To solve this issue outside of a transactional scope you can use

```
Hibernate.initialize(post.getComments());
```

for the post you want the comments to be loaded. However, if you try to access the  comments within a transactional scope you will not need to initialize manually, hibernate will issue query(s) on demand.